# Converting string to datetime problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT PERSONID, 
       CARDEVENTDATE, 
       INTIME, 
       CASE 
         WHEN OUTTIME = INTIME THEN 
           'No PunchOut' 
         ELSE 
            OUTTIME 
       END AS OUTTIME, 
       CONVERT(char(8), CASE 
                          WHEN DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, OutTime), OutTime) > '18:00:00' THEN 
                            Cast('18:00:00' AS datetime) 
                          ELSE 
                            DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, OutTime), OutTime) 
                        END - CASE 
                                WHEN DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, InTime), InTime) < '09:00:00' THEN 
                                  Cast('09:00:00' AS datetime) 
                                ELSE 
                                  DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, InTime), InTime) 
                              END, 8) AS WorkTime
  FROM (SELECT T_PERSON.PERSONID,
               T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE, 
               MIN(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS INTIME, 
               MAX(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS OUTTIME
          FROM T_PERSON 
    INNER JOIN T_CARDEVENT ON T_PERSON.PERSONID = T_CARDEVENT.PERSONID 
      GROUP BY T_PERSON.PERSONID, T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE) DERIVEDTBL
```

---

T_cardevent.cardeventtime column datatype is Varchar.

In table Cardeventtime values are 080002, 091235.... so on...,

When I executing the above query it showing Arithmetic Express Overflow error for converting expression to datatype Datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this "080002" stands for? 8 hours, 0 minutes, 2 seconds?

This is definitely not a valid DATETIME format out of the box - and it doesn't comply with any of the valid [SQL Server CONVERT styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), either.

So you'll have to do some conversions yourself, manually. Is there any chance you could wrap the table with this column into a view which could handle the conversion?

You'd have to do something along the lines of:

```
  CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CardEventTime, 1, 2) + ':' + 
                    SUBSTRING(CardEventTime, 3, 2) + ':' +
                    SUBSTRING(CardEventTime, 5, 2), 8)
```

and this should turn your "080002" into "08:00:02" which can then be converted to a DATETIME (no separate time datatype until SQL Server 2008) using the style no. 8 (hh:mm:ss).

Marc

Comment: @marc_s. But date also displaying like 01/01/1900 08:00:02. I need only the time

Comment: Then use Convert(DATETIME, <string>, 101).   for more info on convert see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @Gopal: in SQL Server 2000, you only have DATETIME which contains both DATE and TIME. Only SQL Server 2008 has a specific TIME data type which is TIME only.

Comment: @tster: the "101" style expects DATES (year, month, day) while the original question was about TIME (hours, minutes, seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a series of assumptions here, and worked without being able to test it, but here's a possible solution:

```
SELECT PERSONID, 
       CARDEVENTDATE, 
       INTIME, 
       CASE 
         WHEN OUTTIME = INTIME THEN 
           'No PunchOut' 
         ELSE 
            OUTTIME 
       END AS OUTTIME, 
    Stuff(Stuff(Right('000000' +
        CONVERT(varchar(5), CASE 
                          WHEN Convert(int,OutTime) > 180000 THEN 
                            180000
                          ELSE 
                            Convert(int,OutTime)
                        END - CASE 
                                WHEN Convert(int,InTime) < 90000 THEN 
                                  90000 
                                ELSE 
                                  Convert(int,InTime) 
                              END), 6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')
        AS WorkTime
  FROM (SELECT T_PERSON.PERSONID,
               T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE, 
               MIN(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS INTIME, 
               MAX(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS OUTTIME
          FROM T_PERSON 
    INNER JOIN T_CARDEVENT ON T_PERSON.PERSONID = T_CARDEVENT.PERSONID 
      GROUP BY T_PERSON.PERSONID, T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE) DERIVEDTBL
```

I've not used Stuff very frequently, so the insertion points may be off.